# Rails Unknown key: :conditions. Valid keys are: :start, :batch_size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I wrote a migration that is pretty beefy, It needs to run over several collections and then do a `find_or_intialize_by` I am doing this within a single transaction and it's taking 80+ seconds to run the query. I want to now try speed this up by using `find_each`.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  StudentApplication.find_each(:conditions => "force_review is true") do |app|
    ....
  end
end
```

I am getting the following:

```
== 20160920133013 MoveForceReviewFieldsToCcSubmission: migrating ==============
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Unknown key: :conditions. Valid keys are: :start, :batch_size/Users/Nexus/Work/prodigy/db/migrate/20160920133013_move_force_review_fields_to_cc_submission.rb:4:in `block in change'
/Users/Nexus/Work/prodigy/db/migrate/20160920133013_move_force_review_fields_to_cc_submission.rb:3:in `change'
/Users/Nexus/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/Nexus/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
ArgumentError: Unknown key: :conditions. Valid keys are: :start, :batch_size
```

Looking at [this tutorial around](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each) using `find_each`, I see it takes a hash argument that allows you to specify a condition to the query, I wanted to take advantage of that to filter the results before running the `find_each`.

we are using `Rails 4.1.14.2` and `ruby 2.3.0p0`, has this option now been deprecated? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you provide is for Rails `2.3.8`.
You can see message that this `find_each` is deprecated.
[image]
You should use [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each) link.
As you can see there is no `conditions` key that is why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 3):

You can use it like this

```
StudentApplication.where(force_review: true).find_each do |app|
  ....
end
```